# Probability of $A \cap B$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> If $P(A) = P(B) = p$, then $P(A \cap B)$ must be less than $p^2$ or more than $p^2$ or cannot determine ?

My attempt is that $P(A \cap B)$ is always less than or equal to $P(A)*P(B)$ given that the two $A$ and $B$ are independent BUT here in question no relation has been given regarding events $A$ and $B$ apart from their Probabilities being equal .

Can we still determine whether $P(A \cap B)$ will be less than p$^2$ ?

Comment: If A and B are independent, then $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$—that is the definition of independence.  If, on the other hand, you know nothing about the two events, then all you know is that $0 \leq P(A \cap B) \leq p$: They might be mutually exclusive, they might be perfectly coincident, or they could be anything in between.  Think about two identical circles (representing A and B) that start out completely disjoint, and slowly overlap until they're right on top of each other.  Their overlap is the probability of their intersection.

Comment: Hint: $Pr( A\cap B)=Pr(A)\cdot Pr(B|A)$. In general $Pr(B|A)\geq Pr(B)$ Therefore $...$

Comment: @callculus; your 'in general' statement is not true. Let B be 'not get a 6 on a d6', A either odd or even. If A is get odd, $Pr(B|A)=1$, if A is get even, $Pr(B|A)=\frac23$. But $P(B)=\frac56$.

Comment: @JMP I cannot comprehend your example. But I´m sure that your numbers are wrong. " *A either odd or even. If A is get odd* " Here you make a additional condition on A. It sounds not right.

Comment: Consider the extremes. Is it possible that there is complete overlap with $A$ and $B$? If so what is $P(A\cap B)$? What about if there is no overlap?

Comment: @callculus As JMP said, the claim that "in general $\mathbb P(B \mid A) \geq \mathbb P(B)$ is false. Consider a fair D6 roll where $A$ is the event of rolling a 6 and $B$ is the event of rolling an odd number.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Thanks for your comment. Your example shows that I was wrong.

Answer (score 4):

If $A=B$, then $Pr(A \cap B)=Pr(A)=p\ge p^2$

Suppose $0<p$ and if $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, then $Pr(A \cap B)= 0 < p^2$.

As you can see, we can't tell if it is bigger or smaller than $p^2$.